# Creating custom backend for cups

Tags: ubuntu, printing, backend, cups

I am trying to create a custom backend, using the "educational backend": [Printing/Developer Tools](https://community.kde.org/Printing/Developer_Tools#.272dir.27_CUPS_backend_script_.28Bash_code.29)

I think everything would work if the backend was recognized....

I copied the contents of the file `2dir`to `/usr/lib/cups/backend/`, set correct permissions (experimented with everything from 700 to 555 to 755). Unfortunately

```
lpinfo -v
```

does not list the `2dir` backend.

What could be the problem ?

Note: I checked for line endings

```
file 2dir
2dir: UTF-8 Unicode English text
```

(because i converted it using `dos2unix`)

Comment: Hi @Thalia, could you let me know what is the 2dir extension? Is it 2dir.sh?

Comment: @TrinhTran No extension. But set its rights to be executable as the link mentioned tells you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script I copied from the site had a leading space in front of the "`#!/bin/bash`" line - and that made the files NOT EXECUTABLE !!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your problem ist solved, but I stumbled upon another problem: Duplicated one backend to generate a new one but didn't change following two lines to match with the new backend name:

```
echo "direct backendname \"Unknown\" \"PDF Creator\""

PDFDIR=${DEVICE_URI#backendname:}
```

(Second line is optional if you want to commit a output path to your backend script).

Maybe this helps someone else.